# Trying to get firebase data to load into component as state and then be edited

Tags: reactjs, firebase, http, redux, axios

I'm struggling to get get data from Firebase to load into a form wizard.

The basic example I am trying right now is just to display some of the firebase data given the collection id.

The current error I am receiving is that there isn't the correct workflow id being parsed into the redux action.

This is the react component

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

//Redux
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getWorkflow } from "../../redux/actions/dataActions";

const example = '3ejAQxPoJ6Wsqsby01S6';

class EoT extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getWorkflow('3ejAQxPoJ6Wsqsby01S6');
  }


  render() {
    const { Workflow} = this.props.data;

    return (<div>
      <p>Crazy</p>
        <h4>{Workflow.createdAt}</h4>
        </div>  
    );
  }
}

EoT.propTypes = {
  getWorkflow: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  data: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state.data
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getWorkflow})(EoT);
```

I have another workflow piece of code that I am using but this is just to test I can load it at all,

this is my api query which works using postman.

```
    // Get Workflow
export const getWorkflow = (WorkflowId) => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: LOADING_DATA });
  axios
    .get(`/Workflow/${WorkflowId}`)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: SET_WORKFLOW,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: SET_WORKFLOW,
        payload: []
      });
    });
};
```

This is the redux action I am using with that query

```
import {
  SET_PROJECTS,
  LOADING_DATA,
  DELETE_PROJECT,
  POST_PROJECT,
  SET_PROJECT,
  SET_CLAIMS,
  SET_CLAIM,
  DELETE_CLAIM,
  POST_CLAIM,
  SUBMIT_COMMENT,
  SET_WORKFLOWS,
  SET_WORKFLOW
} from "../types";

const initialStateProject = {
  Projects: [],
  Project: {},
  Claims: [],
  Claim: {},
  Workflows: {},
  Workflow: {},
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialStateProject, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOADING_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };

    case SET_WORKFLOWS:
      return {
        ...state,
        Workflows: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case SET_WORKFLOW:
      return {
        ...state,
        Workflow: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps explain the problem - I am currently wondering if I can place the id inside it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const getWorkflow = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: LOADING_DATA });
  axios
    .get("/Workflow/:WorkflowId")
```

`:WorkflowId` is not a valid reference here, you need to pass the WorkflowId in as a parameter to this thunk.

Comment: Brilliant I changed it to {WorkflowId}, with = (WorkflowId) passing in, still isn't registering for some reason

Comment: But what is the error now? Is the data being logged successfully? Help us out a little. Turn `/Workflow/${WorkflowId}` into a variable and log it after dispatching LOADING DATA to make sure it is what you expect. Then pass the variable into get.

Comment: If that works then it's likely a backend issue. Can you test the axios call for the correct response?

Comment: I don't understand why you posted a chunk of firebase code that you never use. How is it connected? Does it mirror how you fetch the data on the backend?

Comment: So the firebase code is being used, it's the code to get the data, and is called via the api on cloud function of firebase.

Answer (score -1):

Ended up being that I had to call workflows and not workflow :D